# Python: Multiprocessing is using an undesired value for use in a function

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing

Apologies for the ambiguous title, I'm not sure how to concisely describe my problem.

For simplicity I have written a very short test code which demonstrates the problem I'm having. I am trying to use multiprocessing to create a large data set to be used with plt.imshow to make a heat map.

The test code is as follows (and ignore the fact I am only using a pool of 1, as I said this is just for demonstration purposes):

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

G_list = [1,2,3]
r = 6

def test(G):
    D = np.cos(G)
    E = r*2
    return G, D, E

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)

r_list = []
for i in range(5):
    r += 1
    r_list.append(r)
print r_list

for i in range(len(r_list)):
    r = r_list[i]
    output = pool.map(test,G_list)
    print output
```

The intention of this code was to calculate the values of D and E for the three values of G in G_list, except I want it to do this for a range of values for r. Since pool.map() does not accept a function with multiple inputs, I tried to simple put the pool.map() command inside a for loop which varies r.
The result, however, is this:

```
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
[(1, 0.54030230586813977, 6), (2, -0.41614683654714241, 6), (3, -0.98999249660044542, 6)]
[(1, 0.54030230586813977, 6), (2, -0.41614683654714241, 6), (3, -0.98999249660044542, 6)]
[(1, 0.54030230586813977, 6), (2, -0.41614683654714241, 6), (3, -0.98999249660044542, 6)]
[(1, 0.54030230586813977, 6), (2, -0.41614683654714241, 6), (3, -0.98999249660044542, 6)]
[(1, 0.54030230586813977, 6), (2, -0.41614683654714241, 6), (3, -0.98999249660044542, 6)]
```

As you can see, G is being varied by pool.map() as expected, but the r value is the same each loop despite the fact it is being changed with each loop right before pool.map() is called. My question is, how do I prevent pool.map() using the value of r globally defined at the top, and make it use the value I am changing it to each loop?

Python 2.7, many thanks!

Comment: You could pass a dictionary as parameter to `test`, with one key-value pair being the list, and the other being `r`

Comment: Your `r` value is in the module scope and getting updated in multiple places.  You should pass it into your function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `test` can only accept one input, make the input a tuple.
Then inside of `test`, unpack the tuple into separate variables:

```
def test(task):
    G, r = task
```

Now, when calling `pool.map`, pass a list of tuples as the second argument:

```
tasks = [(G, r) for r in r_list for G in G_list]
output = pool.map(test, tasks)
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing


def test(task):
    G, r = task
    D = np.cos(G)
    E = r*2
    return G, D, E

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(1)

    G_list = [1,2,3]
    r = 6
    r_list = [r+i for i in range(1, 6)]

    tasks = [(G, r) for r in r_list for G in G_list]
    output = pool.map(test, tasks)
    print(output)
```

---

The [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) `r_list = [r+i for i in range(1, 6)]` is equivalent to

```
r_list = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    r_list.append(r+i)
```

Similarly, the list comprehension `tasks = [(G, r) for r in r_list for G in G_list]` is equivalent
to

```
tasks = []
for r in r_list:
    for G in G_list:
        tasks.append((G, r))
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks this worked perfectly and I had never thought to do it like this!